# High Order Buttersworth Filter

Tags: filters, filter-design

Let's suppose i want to implement a Buttersworth filter of order 12 (N=12).
First of all ,I can decompose the Buttersworth polynomial in elemental polynomials:

[image]

Now, if i know how to physically implement the elemental polynomials, how can i construct the original Buttersworth filter of order 12?

Comment: This looks like a classic homework problem - if so we can help you if you show your work and where you are stuck but wouldn’t be cool to do your homework for you.

Comment: Nono, i would like to know only the idea about it

Comment: typo, that's "Butterworth" -- please add that tag too

Answer (score 1):

The impulse response of two filters in series is the convolution of each filters impulse response. You can multiply two polynomials by convolving their coefficients. Likewise you can factor or combine filters by factoring or multiplying their transfer functions described as polynomials.  For example, a fourth order filter can be factored into two 2nd order filters in series, or two 2nd order filters can be combined into one fourth order filter- it’s simply polynomial multiplication or factoring.

So in your case since you already factored the Butterworth filter into individual filters that you know how to implement, you would then simply cascade those filters.

As @MattL points out in the comments, you must pay careful attention to impedances when cascading analog filter sections. In the analog such structures are quite common with active filter design where it is quite simple to isolate the sections with appropriate design techniques, but not so common with filters constructed with passive components.

Comment: That's theoretically correct, but with analog circuitry it doesn't work because each sub-filter loads the previous filter and will influence its behavior. So one would need to use impedance converters between all sections. Normally, one wouldn't want to split up an analog filter like that. That's different with digital filters, of course.

Comment: Yes good point and with LC sections that would be true (not want to split up) with active analog filter design this would still make sense (since each section can be easily isolated).

Comment: Depending on the chosen structure for active analog filter sections, you might still get low input impedances (e.g., inverting op-amp), so I think this has to be checked, even with active filters.

Answer (score 1):

First, all of the "elemental" filters will have the same corner or center frequency. The differences between them will be in their Q.

Consider a second-order Butterworth lowpass filter with a corner frequency of 1 kHz, with a unity-gain passband. At 1 kHz, the response of the filter is -3 dB. The filter slope reaches -12 dB/octave.

The response of a forth-order Butterworth lowpass filter at the same corner frequency is also -3 dB, but its slope reaches -24 dB/octave.

Obtaining a fourth-order slope by cascading two second-order Butterworth filters has a problem: The response at the cutoff frequency would -3 dB + -3 dB, or -6 dB. (The resulting response is sometimes referred to a "Butterworth squared".)

The problem is that in a true fourth-order Butterworth, the poles are distributed evenly on a semi-circle in the s-domain. Cascading two second-order Butterworth doesn't yield the same distribution, and therefore doesn't yield the same response.

The solution is to modify each filter to distribute the poles in the same manner as the higher-order solution. Effectively, this means using two second-order lowpass filters in series, each with different Q settings.

Here is an article with more detail, including a calculator that produces Q values for second-order stages, for Butterworth filters up to order 20:

[Cascading filters](https://www.earlevel.com/main/2016/09/29/cascading-filters/)